# What is the difference between ObservableObject and @State to store a NSWindow object

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, swiftui

I am dynamically/programatically creating windows like this:

```
func createWelcomeWindow() {
    let w = WelcomeScreenView().frame(width: 400, height: 600)
    let hostingController = NSHostingController(rootView: w)
    appState.welcomeWindow = NSWindow(contentViewController: hostingController)
    appState.welcomeWindow?.title = "Welcome to Last Warning"
    appState.welcomeWindow?.collectionBehavior = [.moveToActiveSpace, .fullScreenAuxiliary]
    appState.welcomeWindow?.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
}
```

The appState is being created so:

```
class AppState: ObservableObject {
    @Published var warningWindow: NSWindow?
    @Published var welcomeWindow: NSWindow?
}

@main
struct LastWarningApp: App {
    @ObservedObject var appState = AppState()
```

I am confused about state management in swift.

I tried, mainly out of curiousity, changing for

```
@main
    struct LastWarningApp: App {
        @State var welcomeWindow: NSWindow?
```

And then doing:

```
welcomeWindow = NSWindow(contentViewController: hostingController)
welcomeWindow?.title = "Welcome to Last Warning"
welcomeWindow?.collectionBehavior = [.moveToActiveSpace, .fullScreenAuxiliary]
welcomeWindow?.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
```

But this doesn't create the window, I am wondering why this is, as far as I've understood asking chatGPT, @State seems to be for managing the state of the views and is not suitable for this, I've gone through as much github repos as possible trying to see best practice and I couldn't find clear ways to go about this.

One thing I've noticed, but I am not sure about it, is taht welcome window seems to not be set when I debug it.

So is this a reasonable approach? And why doesn't @State work in this particular case?

It also confuses me that I can do:

```
@State var appState = AppState()
```

And behaviour stays the same.

Comment: Why are you doing this in the first place? This sounds like a giant [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Why do you need to store `NSWindow`s in the first place? How about just doing all this with pure SwiftUI?

Comment: @Sweeper I would be very happy to do it with pure swiftui, but I haven't found any way yet, if I create a windowGroup, this seems to open a window on startup and this is a menubar app that only opens a window under certain situations, I'd be happy to switch to any pure swiftui pure approaches tho, even so I think it's a good learning opportunity.

Comment: Please show a [mcve], one that I can copy and paste into a new project and reproduce the behaviour you have. Right now you only show disconnected pieces of code, and it is unclear where you put them. `createWelcomeWindow` isn't even called, among other things.

Comment: "And this is a menubar app that only opens a window under certain situations" Okay great. That's the actual problem you are trying to solve. Ask *that* question instead. In what situations do you want windows to show? What do the windows show (this might help decide whether to use `WindowGroup` or `Window`)?

Comment: @Sweeper I think that's two different problems, this piece of code works as expected, and I want to understand why the other one doesn't to understand the programming language better, honestly maybe I should remove best practice part as a separate question

Comment: @Sweeper for now it's just a Text("Hello") for all intents and purposes contained in the window.

Comment: @Sweeper I am really not sure how could I give a reproducible example, other that creating a new repo and uploading it to github, is there any macos online playground?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255873/discussion-between-trufa-and-sweeper).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@State` works as a source of truth and redraws the `body` when the “value” changes.

There isn’t anything wrong with

```
@State var appState = AppState()
```

You just have to be aware that changing a property of a reference type does not trigger a redraw because the value isn’t changing.  <<<<< Very important

`ObservableObject` need a series of things to work.

`@Published` emitting when the value changes > `ObservableObject` synthesizing the emission > an “Object” property wrapper to invalidate the `View`.

Now the “gap”, reference types that aren’t `ObservableObject` or `Obervable`, These can be stored with `@State` but won’t redraw the `View` because there is no mechanism.

You may need storage within SwiftUI for these because `View` is a value type and can be recreated at any time by SwiftUI. You will end up with multiple instances if you don’t use it.

There is a difference with the “Object” property wrappers. `StateObject` is for initializing and `ObservedObject` is for passing around.

```
  @ObservedObject var appState = AppState()
```

Is incorrect…..

You should use

```
   @StateObject var appState = AppState()
```

The main difference behind this is having access to the secret storage SwiftUI has.

In iOS 13 “the right” way to initialize an `ObservableObject` was with `State` but we couldn’t observe it until the next view where we could use `ObservedObject`. `StateObject` was introduced in iOS 14.

Now this is the basics of the SwiftUI property wrappers but I think your biggest issue is that you are mixing SwiftUI and AppKit SwiftUI has a very different way of managing windows.

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/10061/

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/bringing_multiple_windows_to_your_swiftui_app

After you design the windows in your `App`.

```
@main
struct BookClub: App {
    @StateObject private var store = ReadingListStore()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ReadingListViewer(store: store)
        }
        Window("Activity", id: "activity") {
            ReadingActivity(store: store)
        }
    }
}
```

You present them something like

```
struct OpenWindowButton: View {
    @Environment(\.openWindow) private var openWindow

    var body: some View {
        Button("Open Activity Window") {
            openWindow(id: "activity")
        }
    }
}
```